# mysql union question

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> select job_desc_title from postings where id=194582;
```

```
+-----------------------------+
| job_desc_title              |
+-----------------------------+
| Speech/Language Pathologist |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

```
mysql> select email_address,first_name,last_name,home_phone_area,home_phone_num from accounts
->  left join profiles on profiles.account_id=accounts.id  
->  where accounts.id=5;
```

```
+--------------------+------------+-----------+-----------------+----------------+
| email_address      | first_name | last_name | home_phone_area | home_phone_num |
+--------------------+------------+-----------+-----------------+----------------+
| newhjh@hotmail.com | Jianhua    | He        | 425             | 3584396        |
+--------------------+------------+-----------+-----------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I need to union the above 2 queries,but my trial failed:

```
mysql> select job_desc_title from postings where id=194582
->                           union all
->                     select email_address,first_name,last_name,home_phone_area,home_phone_num from accounts
->                      left join profiles on profiles.account_id=accounts.id
->                      where accounts.id=5;
```

> ERROR 1222 (21000): The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

What's the right version to do this job?

Comment: I'm trying understand why exactly you need to union these queries? The resulting data from one bears little/no relationship to the others.

Maybe there's a better question to ask or answer here?

Comment: I suppose I'm trying to say something like Eric, below. This looks like something that should be joined, not unioned.

Answer (score 3):

You're selecting job_desc_title form the first one and then email address, first name, last name, etc etc from the second one.  This is not a union.

What you're looking to do is a join, and I suggest you read up on these.  A union takes the results of two queries and combines them vertically.  A join takes the results of two tables and combines them horizontally.  Unions add rows, joins add columns.  What you're trying to do is add a column (job_desc_title), not rows.  Combining rows (i.e.-a union) takes the same columns to work.

I also think that you're using a left join when you should be using an inner join.

```
select 
    a.email_address,
    a.first_name,
    a.last_name,
    a.home_phone_area,
    a.home_phone_num,
    post.job_desc_title
from 
    accounts a
    inner join profiles p on 
        a.id=p.account_id
    inner join postings post on
        --I have no idea what the relationship is here, so I'm guessing
        p.posting_id = post.id
where 
    a.id=5
```

Hopefully this will get you somewhere near the right track.

Answer (score 2):

The two queries that you are unioning together must have the same number of output columns.  Your first select contains one column, your first select contains five columns.

If you wish, you can pad the first select with nulls, as in:

```
select job_desc_title, null, null, null, null from postings where id=194582
```

Comment: right. fake columns might be added, if necessary.
e.g. select column1, 0, 0 from table1 ...

Comment: I'd pad the second select too. as it would union job_desc_title with email address.

Answer (score 1):

yeah

```
select job_desc_title from postings where id=194582
```

and

```
select email_address,first_name,last_name,home_phone_area,home_phone_num from accounts
```

will not union as the need the same number of columns

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

> UNION is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT  statements into a single result set.
>   The column names from the first SELECT statement are used as the column names for the results returned. Selected columns listed in corresponding positions of each SELECT statement should have the same data type. (For example, the first column selected by the first statement should have the same type as the first column selected by the other statements.)

as Robert Harvey states you can add blanks to mis-matching lines

```
select 
    job_desc_title,
    '' AS email_address,
    '' AS first_name,
    '' AS last_name,
    '' AS home_phone_area,
    '' AS home_phone_num 
from 
    postings 
where id=194582
union
select 
    '' AS job_desc_title,
    email_address,
    first_name,
    last_name,
    home_phone_area,
    home_phone_num 
from 
    accounts
```

But this will return you 2 rows for each match.

The more likely scenario is that you want to JOIN both datasets to form one row assuming a 1 to 1 relationship.